# Очень ужасный, очень великолепный

Tags: терминология

Привет. Как называются такие фразы или ситуации вида "очень ужасный", неуместное усиление?

Comment: @november90, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Сочетание "очень ужасный" кажется неуместным. Сочетание "самый ужасный" кажется нормальным, встречается в книгах. Например:

> Верблюд выглядел очень странно: шерсть его скаталась в комки, глаза были совсем тусклые, он спотыкался чуть ли не при каждом шаге, с трудом переставляя ноги, но **самым ужасным** было то, что живот несчастного животного так подтянуло от голода, что он буквально прилип к хребту.

Это не ответ на вопрос, это комментарий (который мне почему-то запрещено добавлять, хотя я ещё ничего плохого не сделал).

Comment: Согласен! Никогда не понимал, почему у новичков нет возможности писать комментарии! Надо это исправить.

Comment: неужели исправили? Спасибо! - Нет, комментарии могу добавлять только к своему вопросу...

Comment: Да нет, Хан, у меня-то нету таких полномочий. Вы неправильно меня поняли: я это высказал как пожелание, а не что будто бы собираюсь сделать. ;)

Comment: Я проголосовал за Ваш "ответ", добавил этим 10 баллов, так скорее доберётесь до нужного количества баллов, чтобы комментировать. ;) 25 что ли нужно... Практически уверен, что в пределах 100.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь некорректная попытка сочетания наречия меры и степени ("очень") с прилагательным, по смыслу имеющим неизменяемую (превосходную) степень.

Comment: Александр, где вы видите превосходную степень прилагательного?

Comment: Я говорю не о форме, а о смысле. Нельзя быть более или менее великолепным, прекрасным или ужасным. Такие прилагательные как "прекраснейший" и "ужаснейший", несмотря на форму словообразования, выражают не повышенную степень того и иного качества, а степень убеждённости говорящего в наличии этого качества.

Comment: Согласен с Alex_ander. Сочетание выглядит довольно "корявым". По поводу "превосходной степени" он, скорее всего, ошибается, но, вот, в идее с "неизменностью" степени - что-то есть. По крайней мере, сочетание "немножко ужасный" выглядит не менее "корявым".

Comment: Так то же самое и с "довольно корявым" = "довольно ужасный"="очень ужасный" 
По смыслу одно и тоже, перебор. 

немного корявый, сильно(очень) пьяный - это не смущает, вопрос почему?

Comment: В том то и дело, что "корявость" может различаться по степени, а, вот, "ужасность" - всегда ужасна.

Comment: По какой степени?  Вот назовите, какая степень корявости характеризует   довольно корявый ствол дерева?
Сильно пьяный - отдельная тема, качает человека. А в стельку - когда уже лежит.

Comment: Я еще сделал по-простому, взял классику, "Капитанская дочка" Пушкина. Поискал слово -- довольно в сочетании и не нашел. Зато у Толстого в первом томе "Война и мир"  раз десять,  а сегодня можно в любой книжке -- раз 50, наверное.

Comment: Я это к чему веду.  Степень превосходности очень(сильно) зависит от того слова к которому относится.  Сила она в действии, и не может применяться к корявости. кривости и подобным словам, довольно--вообще штука неопределенная-штамп вошедший с чье-то легкой руки. есть такое выражение:  Довольно рад.  Тут все понятно, что доволен и рад, или очень рад.
Ужаснее ужаса ничего нет и к нему неприменим эпитет.  Это уже предел допустимого. А вот слова очень, немного, чуть-чуть, несколько вполне показывают меру.

Comment: Это кто Вам сказал?

Во-первых, "очень" и "сильно" - ни разу не синонимы. Т.е. иногда слово "сильно" используют как "заменитель" для "очень". Но это - скорее, жаргон.

Во-вторых, "корявость" можно разложить по степеням, например, так: 1) "почти прямое"; 2) "незначительные изломы, проявляющиеся при обработке"; 3) "множественные изломы, заметные глазу"; 4) "изломы мешают определить "основное" направление"; 5) "основное направление полностью отсутствует". Слово "довольно" характеризует вторую степень.

Ну, и, наконец, "довольно" - это не "очень", а "чуть более, чем немного".

Answer (score 0):

Прилагательные "ужасный и великолепный" являются качественными прилагательные, они имеют сравнительную и превосходную степень и краткую форму (ужаснее, ужаснейший, ужасен), но вот с наречиями степени не сочетаются.

Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что они по структуре близки к  относительным прилагательным (ужасный - вызывающий ужас, связанный с ужасом), а относительные прилагательные с наречиями степени не сочетаются.

Comment: Вера, по сути ''ужаснейший" - это и есть ''очень'' ужасный. Т.к. в прилагательных понятие ''очень'' выражается в превосходной степени. Но вопрос не в этом. Автора интересовала не сочетаемость, а как рассматривать такие сочетания.

Comment: Вера, с возвращением :)

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, приятно Ваше внимание.

Comment: Серж,  у меня к Вам вопрос: добрый – очень добрый – добрейший /самый добрый, разве эти прилагательные не составляют градационный ряд признаков? Мне кажется, что в очень добром меньше доброты, чем в самом добром.  И другой ряд:  страшный – очень страшный (= ужасный) – очень ужасный (нет сочетаемости) – ужаснейший/самый ужасный. Такой ряд тоже неверен?

Comment: Вера, зайдите на Грамота.ру. Именно там в словаре об этом и говорится.

Comment: В английском языке есть какое-то понятие, название которого я запамятовал, но суть такая: существуют прилагательные, уже содержащие значение ярко проявляющегося признака, например "great" ("отлично", "великолепно"), и они не сочетаются с усиливающими наречиями типа "very" ("отлично"). В русском, видимо, такая же ситуация. Вообще, надо помнить, что кроме суперлатива (относительной превосходной степени) есть ещё и элатив (абсолютная превосходная степень). Потому ряда, по сути, два: страшный -> очень страшный -> самый страшный и страшный -> очень страшный -> (или =) ужасный

Answer (score 0):

Это плеоназм, речевая избыточность. Ужасный - очень страшный, второе "очень" лишнее.

Великолепный - высшая степень красивого, роскошного, "очень" - излишество

Превосходная степень некоторых прилагательных дублирует их основное значение:

абсолютнейший

главнейший, самый главный

идеальнейший, самый идеальный

самый наилучший

самый оптимальный

самый безупречный.

[Страничка о плеоназмах](http://www.rodichenkov.ru/Filo/Pleonasm/) (см. внизу):

Избыточные грамматические формы

Comment: Людмила, ваша ссылка не открывается.Не могли бы вы заново привести ее.

Comment: Вчера работала, а сегодня почему-то нет. Вот такой же материал точь-в-точь: http://www.drive2.ru/b/446267/

Comment: Надеюсь, поправил линк.

Answer (score -1):

В стилистике есть фигура - ***гипербола***. Заключается она в явным и намеренном преувеличении, с целью усиления выразительности и подчёркивания сказанной мысли. Например: "я говорил это тысячу раз" или ''нам еды на полгода хватит''.